# Creating a dataframe with datetime in different fields

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to have an ohlc table to later analyze candle patterns, with the current code as you can see below I'm able to see my ohlc table but the "candles" aren't matching the data series.

```
# my testing code
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('tmp/NEG_20180829.txt', header=None, delimiter="\;", skiprows=1,
          names=["Session Date", "Symbol", "Deal Number", "Deal Price",
          "Quantity", "Hour", "Ind Cancel", "Offer Date", "Seq Offer Date",
          "GenerationID", "Deal Condition", "Date Sell Offer", "Sequence Sell Offer",
          "Generation Id Sell", "Sell Condition", "Indicator", "Broker Buy", "Broker Sell"],
          )

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='m')
ticks = df.loc[df.index, ['Deal Price', 'Quantity']]
bars = ticks['Deal Price'].resample('1min', how='ohlc') 
print(bars)
```

and my output:

```
                      open   high    low  close
1970-01-01 00:00:00  18.50  18.50  18.50  18.50
1970-01-01 00:01:00  18.50  18.50  18.50  18.50
1970-01-01 00:02:00  18.50  18.50  18.50  18.50
1970-01-01 00:03:00  18.50  18.50  18.50  18.50
1970-01-01 00:04:00  18.50  18.50  18.50  18.50
1970-01-01 00:05:00  18.50  18.50  18.50  18.50
1970-01-01 00:06:00  18.50  18.50  18.50  18.50
1970-01-01 00:07:00  18.50  18.50  18.50  18.50
1970-01-01 00:08:00  18.50  18.50  18.50  18.50
```

Looks like the pandas aren't able to recognize the data series because as we can see in the file example the day and hour are in different fields, how can I merge them?

File example:

```
2018-08-29;APPL                                             ;0000000290; 000000000018.500000;000000000000002200;10:08:11.899;1;2018-08-29;000082181828559;000000004182711;2;2018-08-29;000082181827277;000000004182712;2;0;00000308;00000021
2018-08-29;APPL                                             ;0000000300; 000000000018.500000;000000000000000100;10:08:11.899;1;2018-08-29;000082181828266;000000004182713;2;2018-08-29;000082181827277;000000004182714;2;0;00000308;00000021
2018-08-29;APPL                                             ;0000000390; 000000000018.500000;000000000000001000;10:08:11.899;1;2018-08-29;000082181826807;000000004182731;2;2018-08-29;000082181828365;000000004182732;2;0;00000003;00000386
2018-08-29;AAPL                                             ;0000000440; 000000000018.500000;000000000000000500;10:08:11.899;1;2018-08-29;000082181825761;000000004182741;2;2018-08-29;000082181827689;000000004182742;2;0;00000003;00000003
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To merge the two fields and convert them to datetime, you can do the following:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Session Date'] + ' ' +  df['Hour'])
```

Then you can set this new column as index with `df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)` and resample as you wanted.

Comment: @Primehaxor I can only recommend updating pandas to the latest version or if that doesn't work installing the same version as on the previous computer.

Comment: The deps were handled via pip freeze > requirements.txt file.

Comment: @Primehaxor Did you switch from Linux to Windows? It might be something with how you are reading in the CSV w.r.t. separators and newline characters.

Comment: hello @Andrey here you can find more details about this curious problem -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355953/valueerror-hour-must-be-in-0-23-pandas-to-sql

Comment: @Primehaxor Your comment is misleading and harmful because the new error is thrown in `to_sql`, which is not present in "this code", it's something you added later. That's an entirely new problem, please be cognizant of that.

Comment: fair enough, removed