# ValueError: hour must be in 0..23 pandas.to_sql()

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code up and running in my other mac, when I moved to a new one I start to see this problem, they have the same timezone and I'm using the same Python version, digging a little bit I didn't find any useful tips to fix it, as i can see the data looks normal but for some reason the pandas.to_sql() is complaining about it:

**Update:**

- Testing with Ubuntu Xenial - Python3.5 - Working
- Mac High Sierra 10.13.6 - Python3.7 - Not Working
- Mac High Sierra 10.13.5 - Python3.7 - Working

Libs were being handled by the requirements.txt file.

**Example of my current data:**

```
0      2017-09-13 10:05:00.009
1      2017-09-13 10:05:00.009
2      2017-09-13 10:05:00.009
3      2017-09-13 10:05:00.009
4      2017-09-13 10:05:00.009
5      2017-09-13 10:05:00.009
6      2017-09-13 10:05:00.009
```

**And here is my sample code:**

```
def RetrieveData(filename=None, papel=None):

    df = pd.read_csv("%s" %(filename), header=None, delimiter="\;",
                skiprows=1, engine='python',
                names=["Session Date", "symbol", "Deal Number", "Deal Price",
                "volume", "Hour", "Ind Cancel", "Offer Date", "Seq Offer Date",
                "GenerationID", "Deal Condition", "Date Sell Offer", "Sequence Sell Offer",
                "Generation Id Sell", "Sell Condition", "Indicator", "Broker Buy", "Broker Sell"],
                )

    df = df[df.symbol.str.contains(papel, na=False)]
    df['period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Session Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Hour'])
    print(df['period'])
    df.set_index('period', inplace=True)

    vol = df['volume'].resample('1d').sum()
    symbol = df['symbol'].resample('1d').sum()
    price = df['Deal Price'].resample('1d').ohlc()
    bars = pd.concat([price, vol, symbol], axis=1)

    bars.rename(columns={
                'open'  : 'ohlc_open',
                'close' : 'ohlc_close',
                'high'  : 'ohlc_high',
                'low'   : 'ohlc_low'}, inplace=True)

    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///database.db')
    bars.to_sql(name='symbol', con=engine, index=True, if_exists='append')
```

**My database definition:**

```
class Symbol(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Symbol'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    symbol = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    volume = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    ohlc_open = Column(Float(10), nullable=False)
    ohlc_high = Column(Float(10), nullable=False)
    ohlc_low  = Column(Float(10), nullable=False)
    ohlc_close = Column(Float(10), nullable=False)
    period = Column(DateTime)
```

**The Exception:**

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2130, in to_sql
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 450, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1127, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 619, in insert
    keys, data_list = self.insert_data()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 600, in insert_data
    d = b.values.astype('M8[us]').astype(object)
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

Comment: I'm using it for the stock market, so during the weekdays each file contains data from 10:00 to 18:00

Comment: sure https://gist.github.com/primehaxor/61e2c63377da0c1db6f9c3ba08d4b262

Comment: I'm using pandas==0.23.4 and Python3.7